# How to highlight / plot one latitude line on map ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, maps, latitude-longitude

I have one map with telemetry data, and I want highlight/plot/add one line of one determinate latitude, which is -51.0000. My `df` have more than 90.000 locations

```
ggplot(df, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_path(size=1, aes(group = id, col = id )) +
  geom_map(data = world_map, map=world_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id), fill="black") +
  xlim(extendrange(df$lon, f=0.05)) +
  ylim(extendrange(df$lat, f=0.05)) +
  coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(-40, -40, 0))+
  geom_contour(data = bat2, 
               aes(x=x, y=y, z=z),
               breaks=c(-200),
               size=c(0.3),
               colour="blue")
```

[image]

Someone how can I add one line, like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: `+ geom_hline(yintercept = 51)`?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much! @r2evans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's simply a `ggplot` object, then use `geom_hline`. I'll use `maps` to start a plot, but all you'll need is the last component of the plot call:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
mp <- map_data("world", region = "Brazil")
ggplot(mp, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = group)) +
  coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(-40, -40, 0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -20, color = "red")
```

[image: brazil with a horizontal line at 21 degrees south]